# Datagrid cell color

Tags: apache-flex

I want to change cell color while user interaction without using itemrenderer. I am able to change fontcolor, fontsize, fontfamily except the cell background color. Is there any way to do this without using itemrenderer?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is none. The ItemRenderer defines how the cell looks.

Comment: @codingbuddha.. Actually while using itemrenderer it'll be slower. i've used the below code..

Comment: override public function set data(value:Object):void
   {
    super.data = value; 
    
   }
   override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
   { 
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
     
bd.setStyle("backgroundColor",getStyle("bgColor"));//bordercontainer
    lbl.setStyle("fontSize",getStyle("fontSize"));//label
    lbl.setStyle("fontFamily",getStyle("fontFamily"));
    lbl.setStyle('color', getStyle("fgColor"));
    lbl.setStyle("fontFamily",getStyle("fontFamily"));
    lbl.setStyle('color',getStyle("fgColor"));
   }

Comment: @codingbuddha....and using style function on datagrid..update displaylist and set data have been called everytime. How can i prevent them to call to every time except when i need?